# No muestra todos los registros al realizar una consulta de SQL SERVER mediante AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sql-server, express

Tengo un problema al obtener todos los registros de una consulta en SQL SERVER por medio de PHP y AJAX.

Cuando realizo el envío POST por el método clásico del form (submit), sin ningún problema se muestran todos los registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, al hacer la consulta por medio del método AJAX, NO visualiza los 5 registros, sólo 4, pero extrañamente el cuarto registro se ve incompleto, incluso no se terminan de generar los

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Archivo de conexion a la BD (conexion_consulta.php):**

```
$cnx=mssql_connect("CRONOS\SQLEXPRESS","consulta","12347"); mssql_select_db("BD_TRAMITE",$cnx);
```

**Archivo consulta.php con el código jQuery y AJAX:**

```
$(document).on("click","#img_Buscar_tramite",function(){
    consulta_tramite();
});

function consulta_tramite()
{
    $('#dv_Contenido').html("<h4>El proceso tardará varios munitos.</h4> <br> <img src='img/cargar.gif'>");
    var codigo_tramite = $('#txt_Valor').val().trim();
    var anio_actual = $('#hdd_Anio_actual').val();

    var cod_tramite = codigo_tramite+'-'+anio_actual;

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'ajax_consulta.php',       
      data: {op:1, cod_tramite:cod_tramite},
   }).done(function(respuesta){
        $('#dv_Contenido').html(respuesta.contenido);
        //$('#sp_Cod_tramite').html(cod_tramite);
   }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, respuesta){
        // Log the error usuarios_online.php
        console.log('The following error occurred: '+ textStatus + ' - ' + jqXHR.responseText + ' - ' + errorThrown);
        $('#dv_Contenido').html('The following error occurred: '+ textStatus + ' - ' + jqXHR.responseText + ' - ' + errorThrown);
    }); 
}
```

**Archivo ajax_consulta.php:**

```
class C_process {

public $contenido = '';

function consulta_tramite()
{
    require_once("../conexion/conexion_consulta.php");
    $cod_tramite = $_POST['cod_tramite'];

    $sql="SELECT iCodTramite,
                cCodificacion,
                fFecRegistro, 
                cDescTipoDoc, 
                cNroDocumento, 
                cAsunto, 
                nFlgEstado, 
                nNumFolio, 
                cReferencia, 
                cObservaciones, 
                nTiempoRespuesta
            FROM Tra_M_Tramite t
            INNER JOIN Tra_M_Tipo_Documento d ON d.cCodTipoDoc = t.cCodTipoDoc
            WHERE cCodificacion ='".$cod_tramite."'";
    $result=mssql_query($sql,$cnx);
    $canr = mssql_num_rows($result);

    if(empty($canr))
    {
        $this->contenido = "<font color='red'><b>Ingrese correctamente el codigo del tramite.</b></font>";
        return;
    }

    $RsTra=MsSQL_fetch_array($result);


    $this->contenido = "<table border='1' width='100%'>
                <tr style='background: #688d40; color: #fff;'>
                    <td style='border: 2px solid #fff;'>Fecha</td>
                    <td style='border: 2px solid #fff;'>Asunto</td>
                    <!--<td style='border: 2px solid #fff;'>Observaciones</td>-->
                    <td style='border: 2px solid #fff;'>Destino</td>
                    <!--<td style='border: 2px solid #fff;'>Responsable / Fecha de Aceptado</td>-->
                    <td style='border: 2px solid #fff;'>Estado</td>
                </tr>";

                $sqlM="SELECT * FROM Tra_M_Tramite_Movimientos WHERE (iCodTramite='".$RsTra['iCodTramite']."' OR iCodTramiteRel='".$RsTra['iCodTramite']."') AND (cFlgTipoMovimiento=1 OR cFlgTipoMovimiento=3 OR cFlgTipoMovimiento=5) ORDER BY iCodMovimiento ASC";
                $rsM=mssql_query($sqlM,$cnx);
                $cant =mssql_num_rows($rsM);
                $contaMov=0;

                $this->contenido .= "<tr><td colspan=4>Cant: ".$cant."</td></tr>";
                while ($RsM=MsSQL_fetch_array($rsM))
                {
                    $this->contenido .= "
                    <tr>
                        <td style='width: 70px;'>".date('d-m-Y', strtotime($RsM['fFecDerivar']))."</td>
                        <td>";

                            $this->contenido .= $RsM['cAsuntoDerivar'];
                        $this->contenido .= "
                         </td>

                        <td>";
                                if($RsM['nFlgTipoDoc']!=3){
                                    $sqlOfiD="SELECT * FROM Tra_M_Oficinas WHERE iCodOficina='".$RsM['iCodOficinaDerivar']."'";
                                    $rsOfiD=mssql_query($sqlOfiD,$cnx);
                                    $RsOfiD=mssql_fetch_array($rsOfiD);
                                    $this->contenido .= trim($RsOfiD['cNomOficina']);
                                }else{
                                    $codi=trim($RsM['cReferenciaDerivar']);
                                    $sqlEstado="SELECT * FROM Tra_M_Doc_Salidas_Multiples WHERE cCodificacion='".$codi."' AND fRecibido is not null ";

                                    //echo $sqlEstado;
                                    $rsEst=mssql_query($sqlEstado,$cnx);
                                    $RsEstado=mssql_fetch_array($rsEst);
                                    if($RsEstado['fRecibido']!=""){
                                        if($RsEstado['cFlgEstado']==1 or $RsEstado['cFlgEstado']==2){
                                                $this->contenido .= "<font size=\"0.5\">Comunicacion Atendida</font>";
                                        }else {
                                                $this->contenido .= "<font size=\"0.5\">Comunicacion En Proceso</font>";
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                            $this->contenido .= "<font size=\"0.5\">En Comunicacion</font>";
                                    }
                                }
                        $this->contenido .= "
                        </td>       

                        <td>";
                                if($RsM['cFlgTipoMovimiento']!=5){  
                                    if($RsM['fFecRecepcion']!=""){
                                        switch ($RsM['nEstadoMovimiento']) 
                                        {
                                            case 1:
                                                $this->contenido .= "En Proceso";
                                            break;
                                            case 2:
                                                $this->contenido .= "Derivado";
                                            break;
                                            case 3:
                                                $this->contenido .= "Asignado";
                                                break;
                                                case 4:
                                                $this->contenido .= "Respondido";
                                            break;
                                            case 5:
                                                $this->contenido .= "Finalizado";
                                                $this->contenido .= "<div style=color:#0154AF;font-size:10px>".$RsM['cObservacionesFinalizar']."</div>";
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                            $this->contenido .= "Pendiente";
                                    }
                                }else{
                                        $this->contenido .= "";
                                }
                                if($RsM['iCodTrabajadorDelegado']!=""){
                                    $rsDelg=mssql_query("SELECT * FROM Tra_M_Trabajadores WHERE iCodTrabajador='".$RsM['iCodTrabajadorDelegado']."'",$cnx);
                            $RsDelg=MsSQL_fetch_array($rsDelg);
                            $this->contenido .= "<div style=color:#005B2E;font-size:12px>".$RsDelg["cApellidosTrabajador"]." ".$RsDelg["cNombresTrabajador"]."</div>";
                                        mssql_free_result($rsDelg);
                                    }
                        $this->contenido .= "
                        </td>
                    </tr>";
                    $contaMov++;
                }
}
```

}

```
$respuesta = new C_process();

$respuesta->consulta_tramite();

echo json_encode($respuesta);
```

Espero sus aportes pues necesito solucionar este problema. Saludos. Gracias.

Comment: Lo unico que veo raro es que usas 2 diferentes metodos, no se si implique pero mira eso `mssql_fetch_array` y `MsSQL_fetch_array`

Comment: que encoding tiene tu bd ytus archivos? quizas sea por las ñ o caracteres especiales, dependiendo de la codificación que estes usando prueba agregarle utf8_encode o utf8_decode antes de imprimir los datos desde la bd.. se está truncando el string por eso no se muestra completo

Comment: Es problema de encode, no deja de mostrar los datos en un punto cualquiera, si no cuando debe mostrar la Ñ.
Debes hacer coincidir el idioma en tu base de datos, en las tablas y columnas. Ademas de en la conexión y en el html. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Para tu ajax debes especificar el tipo de dato en la etiqueta "dataType" y tu has especificado "json" pero estas devolviendo una tabla "html" por lo tanto tu ajax debe quedar asi:

```
$.ajax({ContentType : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        dataType: 'html',
        type : 'POST',
        url: 'ajax_consulta.php',     
        data: {op:1, cod_tramite:cod_tramite}
      })...
```

Creo que tienes algún tipo de problema con el encode "UTF-8", utiliza las cadenas de esta manera para evitar problemas de tildes y la Ñ que es donde tu consulta se detiene(Si ese es el caso).

```
 $this->contenido .= utf8_encode($RsM['cAsuntoDerivar']);
```

Y en tu archivo **ajax_consulta.php** debes incluir 
`header( 'content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );`
que es lo que tu ajax espera recibir; Por ultimo no veo en que momento cierras la tabla 
con la etiqueta `</table>`

Te recomiendo este [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp) para aclarar dudas

Saludos

Comment: yo creo que el error va por otro lado... ya que si le pone las primeras

Comment: Gracias por sus respuestas. Y la verdad todos tienen mucha razón. Todo tiene que ver con los caracteres especiales (ñ, tildes, etc). Y la solución fue usar la función utf8_encode Ejemplo: `utf8_encode($RsM['cAsuntoDerivar'])` Solucionado.
Gracias Mundo.
Saludos.